# How to show $\prod_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}= \frac{2}{3}$?

Tags: analysis

Today, my student ask me how to show
$$
\prod_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}= \frac{2}{3}
$$
I really don't know. So, ask help here.

Comment: First of all the index starts at $n=2$, in other case the product will be zero

Comment: I think you meant $n^3$ in place of $n^2$.

Comment: @Guillerminho77  Sorry, I make a mistake.

Comment: also the product must be $(n^3-1)/(n^3+1)$

Comment: For the corrected cubic version, you can compute the partial products explicitly.  See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=product+%28n%5E3-1%29%2F%28n%5E3%2B1%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+2%2C+infinity%7D) for instance.

Comment: @lulu  It really be $n^2$, not $n^3$.

Comment: But then the result is wrong. If it were $n^2$ the result would be $\pi\operatorname{csch}(\pi)$.

Comment: The quadratic claim is simply wrong.  Easy to see numerically that the quadratic product is around $.27$   In that case you can again compute the partial products explicitly, though it is a lot more work.

Comment: @projectilemotion  Could you talk it detail ? Or give a reference. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the first term in the quadratic case is $\frac 35=.6$ which is less than $\frac 23$, and all the other terms are $<1$.

Comment: Sure. For the $n^2$ case, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449914/the-evaluation-of-the-infinite-product-prod-k-2-infty-frack2-1k2?noredirect=1. For the $n^3$ case, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634973/evaluating-prod-n-2-infty-n3-1-over-n31?noredirect=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\prod_{n=2}^{m}\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\prod_{n=2}^{m}\frac{(n-1)(n^2+n+1)}{(n+1)(n^2-n+1)}=\\
\lim_{m\to\infty}(\frac{1\cdot 7}{3\cdot 3})(\frac{2\cdot13}{4\cdot 7})(\frac{3\cdot21}{5\cdot 13})(\frac{4\cdot31}{6\cdot 21})\cdots\frac{m^3-1}{m^3+1}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Both infinite products $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n-1}{n+1}$ and $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2-n+1}$ are divergent, so your derivation is wrong, even though the result is correct.

Comment: @projectilemotion Infinite products are called convergent only if the limit is not $0$. Not my definition, but the generally accepted one. And, btw, $0\cdot\infty$ isn't much of a result, too.

Comment: Just edited, sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

The correct form of @Guillerminho77's idea would be
$$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}=\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)(n^2+n+1)}{(n+1)(n^2-n+1)}=\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1+\frac1{n(n+1)}}{1+\frac1{(n-1)n}}=\frac1{1+\frac1{1\cdot2}}=\frac23.$$